# Java getMethod throws method not found exception?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am using the `getMethod(String name)` function to load a method but it always throws `MethodNotFoundException`. If I run `class.getMethods()` the method I am looking for is in that result with the exact name I am using to pass to `getMethod()`. The method I am trying to load is a static method so I don't know if `getMethod()` will not work for static methods. Any help?

Comment: Let's see the code that's failing and the output you feel validates your code. :)

Comment: It works for static methodes, too. That's not the problem. -> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Reflection/Overview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the method you're looking for takes any arguments, you need to pass their types to `getMethod()` as well. A Java method's signature (the thing that uniquely defines and identifies a method) is comprised of the method name **and** its parameter types.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: +1, and if it's non-public you need to use `getDeclaredMethod` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The name isn't enough. You have to specify exactly which argument types you think the method takes, otherwise the query might be ambiguous (because Java supports overloading).